# Where is MiniBrowser example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have installed the developer tools for Snow Leopard on my Intel Imac. But i didn't find in /Developer/Exemple/MiniBrowser as explain in some web site. Where i can get this exemple ?

Thank's.

Comment: Maybe you should better ask the guys at Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no /Developer/Examples anymore. All the samples that were in it were either moved to [the website](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/topic_details/resourceType_5.html) or killed off. It appears that MiniBrowser is one of the examples that they killed off.

If you think they shouldn't have killed that one off, you should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) asking for them to put it up on the site. You should cite any Apple documentation that might still be referring to the sample.

Comment: Specific documentation page - definitely just a reference to old example code - the 'last update' is from last year, but the MiniBrowser went some time ago.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/SaveAndLoad.html